# opencv MAT object Array Dynamic allocation with initialization

Tags: opencv

i am new to opencv and has less knowledge on cpp..i need to dynamically create an array of Mat object with the given initial values its giving me error

```
Mat *M=new Mat[variable](rows,cols,CV_8UC1,Scalar(0));
```

error:ISO C++ forbids initialization in array new[-fpermissive]

please suggest a correct syntax for my semantics

Answer (score 2):

You need to initialize them all in a loop:

```
Mat *M = new Mat [variable];
for (int i=0; i<variable; i++)
    M[i].create(rows,cols,CV_8UC1,Scalar(0));
```

Or use a 3-dimensional Mat:

```
int dims[3] = {variable,rows,cols};
Mat M(3,dims,CV_8UC1,Scalar(0));
```

But when you want to read/write images with `imread() or imwrite()`, I suggest using the first solution.